# Question regarding onto and 1-1 functions

Tags: functions

Let $f:A \to B$ be a map which is both 1-1 and onto. Define the map $g:B \to A$ by the following rule: given y in b, let $g(y)$ equal to the unique element x in A such that $f(x)=y$. Show that g is 1-1 and onto.

I don’t even know how to make sense of this problem. I am completely stuck in understanding the body of the question.

Answer (score 3):

This problem is essentially asking you to show that bijections (1-1 functions that are onto) have inverses (and that this inverse is also a bijection). Let $f : A \to B$ be a bijection. For every $y \in B$, there exists a unique point $x \in A$ such that $f(x) = y$. This point $x$ exists because $f$ is onto, and is unique because $f$ is 1-1. Define $g(y) := x$, where $x$ is the point with $y = f(x)$. This gives us a function
$$
g : B \to A.
$$
You can verify directly that $g(f(x)) = x$ for all $x \in A$ and $f(g(y)) = y$ for all $y \in B$. Now, you have to show that $g$ is also 1-1 and onto. More precisely, you have to show the following:

- $g(y_1) = g(y_2)$ implies $y_1 = y_2$ (i.e. $g$ is 1-1)
- for every $x \in A$, there exists $y \in B$ such that $g(y) = x$ (i.e. $g$ is onto).

To prove these two points,  we will need the following
$$
g(f(x)) = x \quad \text{and} \quad f(g(y)) = y
$$
for all $x \in A$ and $y \in B$.

We now prove that $g$ is 1-1. Suppose that $g(y_1) = g(y_2)$, applying the function $f$ to both sides of this equality gives:
$$
y_1 = f(g(y_1)) = f(g(y_2)) = y_1.
$$
Hence, $g$ is 1-1. I will leave it to you to verify that $g$ is onto (use that $g(f(x)) = x$ for all $x \in A$).

Comment: Why can you say that $g(b)=a$?

Comment: This is how I define the function $g(b)$. For a point $b \in B$, I know there exists a unique point $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = b$. I then define $g(b) := a$. Note that this is how the problem tells us to define the function $g$.

Comment: In your explanation is x represented as little a and y represented as little b? I’m still very confused, been trying for an hour trying to understanding this problem

Comment: Yes $a$ is $x$ and $b$ is $y$. By force of habit I used these letters since our sets are $A$ and $B$. I will edit my answer and replace them with $x$ and $y$.

Comment: The problem tells you how to construct the function $g$. In my answer, I was explicit with this construction. The problem now asks you to show that $g$ is 1-1 and onto.

Comment: I am starting to understand it now, I was over complicating the problem a bit, thanks for clearing this up!

Comment: I added some information to my answer, hope this helps.

Comment: I feel like in the proof you are just going back and using things that were already stated, isnt the definition of $g(y)=x$?

Comment: Yes, I am clarifying the definition of the function $g$.  However,  I am pointing out a property that will make the proof very quick.

Comment: For the 1-1 proof are you using both the $f(g(y))=y$ and $g(f(x))=x$ equations? (Sorry for asking so many questions, this is the first proof that I have done)

Comment: No I am only using that $f(g(y)) = y$. For the "onto proof" you will need the other equation.